# using scanf and family to read in two strings separated by a space from a file in c

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read in 2 string that are separated by a space from a file.

Whatever I try I keep getting the 1st string initialized but the second string is always NULL.

Some of the formatters that I have tried are `"%s%s"` , `"%s %s"` , `"%s[\n\t ]%s"`

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

I think it has to do with the internal buffer of scanf -- reads the first `%s` then puts some invisible character in buffer reads that with 2nd `%s` which then is read and the second string is `NULL` when complete.

Comment: Can you post your complete code sample?

Comment: If you just posted your code and the input then it would be trivial to answer. At the moment we have to guess. Never a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

What do your strings look like?

I don't think your hypothesis of fscanf() modifying the input data by placing "some invisible character in buffer" is true.

It seems more likely that your strings don't conform to the requirements of the %s format specifier.

Comment: My hypothesis might be wrong but both of the string confirm to %s.

Comment: The two strings are aa and bb

Answer (score 1):

between your string, if there is **just** one space

fscanf ( ..., "%s %s", ... ) ; // you know how to fill space marked with ...

but if number of white space is not known :

```
char stack[YourscreenSize];
fscanf ( ..., "YourscreenSize[^\n]", stack );  // take all line in one data,
```

then parse it

if number of white space is not known, ( second way )

- take data from file
- check it,   send first char in isgraph function whether it is white space or not
- if it is white space, then erase stored data

do it, iteratively.When you see EOF break from iteration, (you can chech return value of 
fscanf to know whether it reads char or EOF )

Comment: I know that there is exactly 1 space between them